# How to output only a single curl value in php

Tags: php, curl

I would like to output a temperature for example 12.8 with curl in php. With my basic curl php code i can output all the input. But i only need to output the desired temperature information. How to do this?

**INPUT**

With browser use username and password = demo:

http://demo.pimatic.org/api/variables/variable-set.temperature

**CODE**

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://demo:demo@demo.pimatic.org/api/variables/variable-set.temperature");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
print $result;
?>
```

**GIVES OUTPUT**

```
{ "variable": { "name": "weather.temperature", "readonly": true, "type": "attribute", "value": 12.8, "unit": "°C" }, "success": true }
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

12.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract it from this json string by decoding it and getting demanded value:

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);// decode to associative array
$result = $result['variable']['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON and then output just the value you want:

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $result->variable->value;
```